Override Spring Boot version in Spring Cloud
In Spring Cloud documentation https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud
it is stated that we can use spring-cloud 2020.0.6 and use spring-boot 2.5.x
I am using spring-cloud 2020.0.6 as my parent
and I am importing spring-boot dependencies as in my pom file
It's still pulling spring-boot 2.4.13 as in spring-cloud 2020.0.6
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/blob/136024fcd361e908e59f3e151a147abab466a251/spring-cloud-starter-parent/pom.xml#L8
I searched but couldn't find an answer related with this (You can upgrade spring version with properties)
pom file:
    <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2020.0.6</version>
    </parent>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.15</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
    </dependencyManagement>


You shouldn't use spring cloud as your parent. Use spring boot as the parent.

@spencergibb could you please explain why? thanks in advance

So you can update the boot version independently of cloud. Spring cloud usually supports 2 minor versions of boot

Thanks @spancergibb I have changed the parent and it fixed my problem. Now I include sring-cloud separately
